# ECS BlueGreen Deployment using CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am getting below error while running AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup in Cloudformation.

> For ECS deployment group, loadBalancerInfo must not contain targetGroupInfo list (Service: AmazonCodeDeploy; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidLoadBalancerInfoException;

Cloudformation template that I am using.

```
  AppDeploymentGroup:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
    DependsOn:
      - EcsService
      - LoadBalancer
      - TargetGroupBlue
      - TargetGroupGreen
      - AutoScalingTarget
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref AppDeployApplication
      DeploymentGroupName: !Ref CodeDeployDeploymentGroupName
      DeploymentStyle:
        DeploymentOption: WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL
        DeploymentType: BLUE_GREEN
      DeploymentConfigName: CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce
      BlueGreenDeploymentConfiguration:
        DeploymentReadyOption:
          ActionOnTimeout: CONTINUE_DEPLOYMENT
          WaitTimeInMinutes: 0
        TerminateBlueInstancesOnDeploymentSuccess:
          Action: TERMINATE
          TerminationWaitTimeInMinutes: 5
      LoadBalancerInfo:    
        TargetGroupInfoList:
          - Name: !Ref TargetGroupBlue
          - Name: !Ref TargetGroupGreen
      ServiceRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      ECSServices: 
        - ClusterName: test
          ServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
```

what mistake am I doing?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do this?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation **does not support** b/g deployments for ECS using `AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup`. They are [only for lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codedeploy-deploymentgroup-loadbalancerinfo.html):

> AWS CloudFormation supports blue/green deployments on the AWS **Lambda compute platform only**.

But, there is **fully separate procedure** (not involving `AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup`) for b/g on ECS with CloudFormation:

- [Perform ECS blue/green deployments through CodeDeploy using AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/blue-green.html)

Comment: Thanks, Is there any other way for BG deployment using Capacity Provider?